# How to paste text from an external source into the xterm edited file?

Tags: xterm, paste

I want to copy some text from a webpage and paste it into a file opened with xterm editor. How can I paste my text into the xterm edited file?

Comment: try middle-click or shift-insert to paste inside xtrem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `xterm` middle click works for me, as does <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. There possibly are other methods, but those are the ones I just tested.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. I have been in a big trouble this morning. Your command is so simple and does not require any tool to install.

Answer (score 3):

Give a try to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for pasting text (*which are copied from external sources*) into `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried before posting my question and it did not succeed.

Comment: @begueradj it works for me.

Comment: I am very sorry, the file is opened with XTERM. I will edit my question. Sorry.

Comment: Haha, nice joke, @begueradj ))

Comment: I am inside a big fantastic slight ... zero usefulness
ok, @begueradj thank you for your nano circumference ))

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to run Nano with multibuffer option

```
nano -E
```

then use both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>